# Replace for Tilecache?

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, mapserver, tilecache, cygwin

I tried to use Tilecache with my mapserver/openlayers/postgis/cygwin configuration, but no success so far, I just got tired of keeping digging in the whole system to get that thing working.

So, could anyone please suggest some cache tools that instead can be used with mapserver/openlayers/postgis/cygwin? (...yeah, I have to use cygwin)

Any hints are welcomed,

Comment: I would check MapProxy first. Cygwin may be hard for MapCache. If you can run java and Tomcat or Jetty then GeoWebCache is worth trying.

Comment: @user30184 thanks for the tip, I have tomcat-7.0.56 succesfully running, but there is no conflict between GeoWebcache and mapserver? I had the impression that the latter only works with geoserver. I do have geoserver succesfully running, but my WMS layers are served by mapserver

Comment: GWC can proxy any WMS. Manual for stand-alone GWC tells how but adding new cache layers into geowebcache.xml works similarly with the integrated GWC if you already run it with GeoServer.